# NodeJS аутентификация

Tags: javascript, node.js

Здравствуйте. Проблема, наверное, глупая, но я не могу написать нормальную аутентификацию на node js. Важно сделать это без express. Я нашла способ сделать это с помощью заголовка, но я не поняла как его применить к нормальной красивой html-ой форме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, function (email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({
        email: email
    }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!user || !user.authenticate(password)) {
            return done(null, false);
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
}));
```